# Quartz.Net How To Log Misfire

Tags: quartz.net

I am using Quartz.Net and we regularly see misfires during development and live. Whilst this is not a problem as such we would like to enable some sort of tracing so in development it is possible to see when a misfire occurs.

Are there any events we can hook into for this purpose? Ideally I am after something like...

```
var factory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
var scheduler = factory.GetScheduler();
scheduler.Start();

scheduler.OnMisfire += (e) => {
    Console.Out.WriteLine(e);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a trigger listener to handle this, see [Lesson 7: TriggerListeners and JobListeners](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/trigger-and-job-listeners.html).

You can use the [history plugin](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/tree/master/src/Quartz/Plugin/History) as a reference for building your own logging.

### Example

```
class MisfireLogger : TriggerListenerSupport
{
    private readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger (typeof (MisfireLogger));

    public override void TriggerMisfired (ITrigger trigger)
    {
        log.WarnFormat("Trigger {0} misfired", trigger.Key);
    }
}

scheduler.ListenerManager.AddTriggerListener (new MisfireLogger ());
```

Comment: History page is not found